# windows service wait for timer and never close on its own

Tags: c#

I created a windows service project with Visual Studio. This service should run in the background and poll data every X seconds. The polling is achieved with a timer and a tick event. So whenever the tick event is raised the service should do something.

Unfortunately the service closes itself because it does not wait for the timer to tick. The `OnStart` method gets executed and runs but after that the service closes itself.

I added a debug mode to my program file

```
        private static void Main()
        {
#if DEBUG
            new RuntimeService().RunDebugMode();
#else
            ServiceBase.Run(new RuntimeService());
#endif
        }
```

and use this code for my service application

```
public partial class RuntimeService : ServiceBase
{
    private const int BATCH_POLLING_INTERVAL = 3000;

    private Timer batchPollingTimer;

    public RuntimeService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void RunDebugMode()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // ...

            batchPollingTimer = new Timer(BATCH_POLLING_INTERVAL);
            batchPollingTimer.Elapsed += OnTimer;
            batchPollingTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        batchPollingTimer.Enabled = false;

        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }

    private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        batchPollingTimer.Enabled = false;

        // ...

        batchPollingTimer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

How can I run the service without closing it and waiting for the timer ticks? By "closing itself" I mean executing the Main method and ignoring the timer. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: "Unfortunately the service closes itself", you mean the service is shutdown? by itself? The fault tolerance is configure to restart? does the service encounter an error in the sys log? Or Service quit the debug mode before the tick?

Comment: By "closing itself" I mean executing the Main method and ignoring the timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only do this in debug mode, because there is nothing stopping it from ending. Ordinarily ServiceBase.Run will not return unless the service is shutting down. Add a sleep for a long time so that after your main thread has kicked off your timer, it will go to sleep rather than exiting the Main

Something like:

```
    private static void Main()
    {
#if DEBUG
        new RuntimeService().RunDebugMode();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
#else
        ServiceBase.Run(new RuntimeService());
#endif
    }
```

As an aside, consider putting your timer stop/start in a try/finally - at the moment if something happens in your OnTimer, your stopped timer will never restart and your service will cease doing anything (but may not crash entirely)

```
private void OnTimer(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  try{
    batchPollingTimer.Enabled = false;

    // ...
  } finally {
    batchPollingTimer.Enabled = true;
  }
}
```

}